# How to format updateMask in order to update Web Stream Url?

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I try to update a stream url using the API[1].
The request body implemented by Google UI suggest that we can update the defaultUri.[2]
The update should work only with an appropriate updateMask[3].
Following the documentation, I'm using webStreamData.defaultUri updateMask.
However, the API returns an 400 error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "One or more values in the field 'update_mask.paths_list' was invalid, but all values must be valid: web_stream_data.default_uri",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

I've also tried with web_stream_data.default_uri but it returns the same error.

Could you help me to find the correct updateMask ?

Kind regards,
Patricia

[1]https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties.dataStreams/patch

[2]Request body

```
{
  "webStreamData": {
    "defaultUri": ""
  }
}
```

[3]https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.FieldMask

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying updateMask as a query parameter.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties.dataStreams/patch?updateMask=web_stream_data.default_uri

or

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1beta/properties.dataStreams/patch?updateMask=webStreamData.defaultUri